# Overriding routevalues for childaction

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an index view that takes the page parameter like so:

```
/News?page=2
```

But in the layout for that view I have this childaction:

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Index", "Comments", new {page=1, pagesize = 10});}
```

But the querystring "page" remains 2.. how come? And how to override page for the childaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>That's because the child action first looks at the original request query string when binding for values and after that the one passed as argument to the `RenderAction` helper. You could use a different name for this parameter to avoid this ambiguity.</strike>

---

UPDATE:

Unable to reproduce the behavior you are describing.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult Test(string page)
    {
        return Content(page, "text/html");
    }
}
```

View (`~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml`):

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Test", "Home", new { page = 1 });}
```

When querying `/Home/Index?page=5` the correct value 1 is shown and the `page` parameter in the child action is 1.

Obviously if inside your child action you are fetching this value manually from the request it won't work but that's not something you should be doing anyways:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Test()
{
    string page = Request["page"] as string;
    return Content(page, "text/html");
}
```

Comment: That would solve the problem of course, but only temporarily. If I suddenly implement the childaction in another view, then it's easy to forget checking if the parent action also uses that new querystring, isn't there a way I can override?

Comment: Hmm ok, yeah I was directly getting the querystrings from the request, I changed it now to public ActionResult Index(int page, int pagesize)

But can you clarify why the practice of doing that is bad?

Comment: @Martin Hansen, because that's what the model binder is supposed to do. When you are getting values manually from the request string you will only get string properties which you will need to cast back to their original type, validations won't run, won't be able to handle complex objects, you will have problems as the one you just described, ... hundredths of reasons why you should never fetch values manually and leave this to the binder.